# Android facebook api, get diffrent size profile picture

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using the relatively new Facebook graph api.
I'm getting a list of friends and their profile pics that use the app.

I'm not sure how to modify the parameters that I'm sending so that the picture that is returned is large. The default one that's returned currently is to small.

I'm using the newMyFriendsRequest.

the parms I send it look like this...

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "picture,name");

request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Not sure how to add a parm to that requests so the picture returned to me is large.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requesting `/user-id/picture?type=large` gives you a larger version of the profile picture.

You can use `type` in the request you are making like this,

```
parameters.putString("fields", "picture.type(large),name");
```

Comment: Spot on. Cheers mate.